# Iterate through Oracle SQL query results line by line, and produce sub-queries

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

If have the below query (simplified example of my query, for the purposes of readability):

```
SELECT make, year, color, count(*) 
FROM cars
GROUPY BY make, year, color
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

I want to iterate through the resulting table and produce sub queries for the criteria of each row (examples below). I hope to then use these sub queries to make a single table with samples results (maybe 3 rows) that meet the criteria of each of the rows from the original query results (ex. as there are multiple Jeeps from 2019 in color black).

```
SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Jeep'
AND  year = '2019'
AND color = 'Black';


SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Ford'
AND year = '2018'
AND color = 'Red';
```

This may seem like an odd or unnecessary request. However, I believe that this is the best approach given the complexity of my actual problem. This is the approach I want to take, as I want a simplified solution that I can come back to and alter for future use and for different variations of queries.

Perhaps I could use a PLSQL procedure that creates a temporary table that will store the values from each line? I was thinking I could store column values in variables, so that I could build my subqueries from those. Let me know what you think, or if you have a better approach. Thank you!

NOTE: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Humour us, what's your actual problem? This is almost screaming for a simple analytic count function.

Comment: feel free to provide your approach! It just that one problem I have is that I hope to come back and reuse this procedure for different variations of queries. So if you have an idea for a function that would take a query as input that'd be great.

Comment: There's already an answer which is going along the same lines as I would (just missing the `count(*) over (partition by make,year,color)` ) - one pass of the table rather than one plus several extra queries (needing large indexes to support)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to retrieve a maximum of three rows per group. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select c.*,
    row_number() over(partition by make, year, color order by id) as rn
  from cars c
) x
where rn <= 3
```

Result:

```
 MAKE  YEAR  COLOR  ID   RN 
 ----- ----- ------ ---- -- 
 1     2     3      100  1  
 1     2     3      101  2  
 1     2     3      102  3  
 4     2     3      104  1  
 4     2     3      105  2  
 4     2     7      106  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c66a5448a4d994278097707c18726261).

Comment: so I'm trying to use multiple tables other than cars. But i'm getting a disconnected from the rest of the join graph error when doing this. Should I still be able to do this approach with multiple tables?

Comment: As a general answer, yes it's most likely possible to use this strategy with multiple joins and related tables. However, it's difficult to say with certainty wihout seeing the actual details. I would ask another question.

Comment: I provided the query in the below link. Thanks for the ongoing help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841345/table-is-disconnected-from-the-rest-of-the-join-graph

Comment: it seems that the solution you provided is taking quite long to run. The details of the query are attached in the above link. Let me know if you have any suggestions. When I go through the process manually (that I hope to automate with this query), the runtime to produce the desired output doesn't take too long (an hour or two). However, when I run your solution it remains running for the entire day and then Oracle stops the process as a result of the database connection timing out. Let me know what you think!