# Table is disconnected from the rest of the join graph

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, join

For my below query for table 1, I am getting error

> "disconnected from the rest of the join graph."

I have had this issue in the past and have simply re ordered table references around as well as identifiers and that has fixed it. However, I can't seem to fix it this way.

```
select *
from (
  select table1.*, table2.*, table3.*, 
  row_number() over (partition by table1.date1,
        table1.PRODUCT_DESC,
        table1.PRODUCT_SUB_TYPE_CD,
        table3.TYPE_CPY,
        table3.entity order by table1.PRODUCT_DESC) as rn
    from table1, table2, table3
) x
where rn <= 3
and x.code1 = x.code2 
and x.account_key = x.code1
and table1.date1 between '01-APR-19' and '01-APR-21'
and x.PRODUCT_DESC = 'text'
and x.PRODUCT_SUB_TYPE_CD = 'text'
and  x.TYPE_CPY = 'text'
and x.entity = 'N'
order by x.PRODUCT_DESC;
```

*NOTE: I am using Oracle SQL developer

Comment: after subquery you you don't have table1 or tbale3 or table2 , its all x

Comment: Why aren't you including the join conditions in the subquery (and using ANSI join syntax)? And are you actually getting an error when you run the query (with the x changes; though ending up with `x.code = x.code` probably isn't what you meant), or is that just a SQL Developer warning - I think it's the latter, so might be a version issue, potentially.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. You are both correct, I fixed those two things (I changed variable names for the question). It is currently running and will update if it is outputs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

first always you explicit join , then :

```
select *
from (
  select table1.*, table2.*, table3.*, 
  row_number() over (partition by table1.date1,
        table1.PRODUCT_DESC,
        table1.PRODUCT_SUB_TYPE_CD,
        table3.TYPE_CPY,
        table3.entity order by table1.PRODUCT_DESC) as rn
    from table1
    join table2 on table1.code = table2.code -- ?
    join table3 on table3.code = table1.code -- ?
) x
where rn <= 3
and x.account_key = x.cod
and x.date1 between '01-APR-19' and '01-APR-21'
and x.PRODUCT_DESC = 'text'
and x.PRODUCT_SUB_TYPE_CD = 'text'
and x.TYPE_CPY = 'text'
and x.entity = 'N'
order by x.PRODUCT_DESC;
```