# Oracle SQL Developer - error when referencing fields within nested from statements

Tags: sql, oracle

For the below query I am getting an error with line 4 when referencing variables within "y". The query runs successfully when I use just " y.* " (line 5), however it generates an error when I try to also pull from the specified fields in line 4 (y.field1 as PRODUCT, y.field2 as PRODUCT_TYPE, y.entity, y.TYPE1). For the output, I want these fields listed first for visual reference.

I have this approach/ logic working for other queries (as i'm re using this logic for multiple variations of queries and various tables). However, I think that the issue with this one lies in my attempt to reference fields from tables that are in my join statements.

```sql
(
select 
       -- categorization fields: 
       -- table2.field1 as PRODUCT, table2.field2 as PRODUCT_TYPE, table3.entity, table3.TYPE1
       y.field1 as PRODUCT,
       y.field2 as PRODUCT_TYPE,
       y.entity,
       y.TYPE1
       ,y.*
from   (
  select *
  from   (
    -- table references:
    select table1.*,
           row_number() over (
             partition by
             -- categorization fields: 
             table2.field1,
             table2.field2,
             table3.entity,
             table3.TYPE1 
             order by table3.entity
           ) as rn
    -- table references
    from   table1
    -- joins, links, and filtering: 
           inner join table6  on table1.field_1 = table6.code1
           inner join table5  on (table6.code = table5.code1)
                              AND (table6.code = table5.code) 
            left join table3  on table6.ent1 = table3.ent_code
            left join table2  on table1.extid = table2.extID
    where  table1.tdate between '01-APR-19' and '01-APR-21'
    AND    table1.refe NOT IN ('OFF')
  ) x
  -- sample rows:
  where rn <= 2
) y
);
```

Let me know if anyone has a way that I can maybe better specify which tables those fields come from. I wish I could just do something like this:

```
y.table2.field1 as PRODUCT,
y.table2.field2 as PRODUCT_TYPE,
y.table3.entity,
y.table3.TYPE1
```

Sorry that I don't have a fiddle available!

Comment: You are using `SELECT table1.*` so its very easy to determine where they come from; they're all from `table1` and not any other table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840026/iterate-through-oracle-sql-query-results-line-by-line-and-produce-sub-queries

Comment: above is a link to my original question for this problem

Comment: That link suggests you're seeing "disconnected from the rest of the join graph", which is a SQL Developer warning, not an error, and is not always reliable - if you're using an older version, upgrade and see if it goes away on its own. Or are you getting a real ORA-nnnnn error as well? I'm not sure why you wouldn't include that information in the question, either way.

Comment: disregard the "disconnected from the rest of the join graph" I had copied provided solution incorrectly

Comment: So what error are you getting, and why don't you want to tell us?

Answer (score 0):

> Let me know if anyone has a way that I can maybe better specify which tables those fields come from.

Don't use `select *`. Instead, use the column names and give them appropriate aliases so you know where they came from:

As an example:

```
SELECT small_value,
       medium_value,
       big_value
FROM   (
  SELECT small.value  AS small_value,
         medium.value AS medium_value,
         big.value    AS big_value
  FROM   big
         CROSS JOIN medium
         CROSS JOIN small
)
WHERE  1 = 1
```

In your query, instead of using `SELECT *` in `y` or using `SELECT table1.*` in `x` you can name the columns and give them descriptive aliases.

> I  am getting an error with line 4 when referencing variables within "y".
>
> ```
> (
> select 
>        -- categorization fields: 
>        -- table2.field1 as PRODUCT, table2.field2 as PRODUCT_TYPE, table3.entity, table3.TYPE1
> ```

That is because you cannot see `TABLE2` or `TABLE3` because the only "view" you are looking at is of the sub-query with the alias `y`.

If you want to see those columns then you need to `SELECT` them inside the `x` subquery and pass them to each subsequent outer-query.

```sql
(
  select *
  from   (
    -- table references:
    select table1.field1 AS t1_product,
           table1.field2 AS t1_product_type,
           table1.entity AS t1_entity,
           table1.type1  AS t1_type1,
           table2.field1 AS t2_product,
           table2.field2 AS t2_product_type,
           table2.entity AS t2_entity,
           table2.type1  AS t2_type1,
           table3.field1 AS t3_product,
           table3.field2 AS t3_product_type,
           table3.entity AS t3_entity,
           table3.type1  AS t3_type1,
           row_number() over (
             partition by
             -- categorization fields: 
             table2.field1,
             table2.field2,
             table3.entity,
             table3.TYPE1 
             order by table3.entity
           ) as rn
    -- table references
    from   table1
    -- joins, links, and filtering: 
           inner join table6  on table1.field_1 = table6.code1
           inner join table5  on (table6.code = table5.code1)
                              AND (table6.code = table5.code) 
            left join table3  on table6.ent1 = table3.ent_code
            left join table2  on table1.extid = table2.extID
    where  table1.tdate between '01-APR-19' and '01-APR-21'
    AND    table1.refe NOT IN ('OFF')
  ) x
  -- sample rows:
  where rn <= 2
);
```

Comment: thanks for this idea. The thing is I want to do a select *  because there are dozens of variables in table1 so it would be super inconvenient to list them all. I hope to pull all fields that's why I did *

Comment: @KyleStrougo You cannot when you have columns with the same names in two different joined tables. You need to provide aliases for the columns of at least one of the joined tables so that the column names are unique. So, in your case, `SELECT *` cannot work in the inner-most query.